# the meaning of "thick"

Tags: meaning

> Feral horses, belonging to my grandfather, ran wild over **thick banks
>   of water hemlock**, and there were more than a few rattlesnakes.
>   <sub>[*Educated: A Memoir*
>   by Tara Westover](https://www.20somethingreads.com/reviews/educated-a-memoir/excerpt)</sub>

I was told it is like "thick forest", so thick does not modify banks even it is "thick banks of".

> He was standing at the head of the table; the rest of us perched on
>   benches, studying **the thick planks of red oak**.
>   <sub>ibid</sub>

Here, I think thick is for planks

So, my question would be in the form of "the thick A of B", which one does thick modify, A or B?

Comment: “Thick banks of water hemlock” sounds very odd to me. It describes the banks as being thick, rather than the hemlock. I would expect “Banks (covered) with water hemlock growing thick” or words to that effect. Where is the quote from?

Comment: the book <educated> by TARA WESTOVER

Comment: From the full OED definition BI1b ***figurative**. The position, time, stage, or state in which activity is **most intense; the midst, the height** (of an action). Always **in the thick of.*** Commonly today, ***in the thick of it*** = ***at the heart of some [hectic] activity***. Only distantly related to adjectival *thick planks*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Also seems quite distantly related to _thick banks of hemlock_ (which is also adjectival). I don’t see how _the thick of it_ relates to the question?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Ooops - misread OP's **the thick A of B** as **the thick of A and B** (as in *Soho was right in the thick of parties and orgies back in the 60s*). I assume the water hemlock grows densely / thickly crowded on the banks, and obviously *[red oak] **planks*** is the relevant noun for the second one.

Comment: I understand it as "banks that are thick with water hemlock", which is what I first read it as meaning: I didn't see the ambiguity until I went over it again!

Comment: Whoever wrote “Thick banks of water hemlock” was using "thick" to describe their skull, I suspect.

Comment: _Bank of flowers_ is hardly an unknown collocation. Both water hemlock and rattlers are deadly poisonous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Thick banks of water hemlock

To me this conjures a picture of exuberant collections of water hemlock *appearing* to form islands or banks within a marshy field.

Remember that water hemlock, *Cicuta virosa*, likes to grow in wet grassland, sometimes called "water meadow".

[image: Water meadow, the typical place to find water hemlock]

It is implausible that wild horses would be making a special point of running along the very edge of a river. It is more plausible that they were running through wet grasslands / water meadow, such as that shown above, and that the "banks" were not edges of a river, but rather random clusters of water hemlock.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the question :
*... "the thick A of B", which one does thick modify, A or B?*

Option A because I interpret your examples as :

- the thick (i.e. dense) banks [of flowers]
- the thick (i.e. several cm wide) planks [of red oak]

Perhaps the confusion is that *thick* has multiple meanings.  In second sentence I’d interpret it as :

> growing close together and in large amounts:
>   *thick forest.
>
>   thick, dark hair*.
>   —  [cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thick)

Likewise, *bank* has various meanings, and I read it here as

> bank noun (3)
>   : a group or series of objects arranged together in a row or a tier.
>   *a bank of vending machines*
>   — [merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bank)